# Django custom user model : User creation issue

Tags: python, django

I am have created a custom user model to replace username with email. But when I am trying to add user from Django Admin I get error:

```
 Please correct the errors below.
```

There is no other information with that error message.

The code for custom user:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="email_address",
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
    )

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Custom User Manager Code:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email is required")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and     password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if kwargs.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff True")
        if kwargs.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser True")
        return self._create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
```

and the admin code for same:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserCreationForm

    list_display = ('id', 'email', 'is_superuser')
    list_filter = ('is_superuser',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_superuser', 'is_staff')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = fieldsets

    search_fields = ('name', 'email')
    ordering = ('name', 'email')

    filter_horizontal = ()
```

Custom User Form:

```
# users/forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'email')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'email')
```

I have tried many changes but couldn't figure out the issue. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Have you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py`? Also, can you post the code for `CustomUserCreationForm`?

Comment: @WillKeeling Yes, I have added that to my settings. Also I have updated the code with CustomUserCreationForm.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('name', 'email')`

To:

`class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('name', 'email')`