# Django admin wont let me log in with a custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I've done a custom user model and when I try to log in to django admin it says "Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.".

I've tried creating a superuser using python manage.py createsuperuser but it returns:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 156, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

I've tried creating a user through `CustomUser.objects.create(email=email, ...)`

I've tried checking if it is a staff, superuser and active. All of these returned True.

**Code**

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    full_name = models.CharField(_('full name'), max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(_('session id'), max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    verification_code_time = models.IntegerField(_('time left for session id'), null=True, blank=True)
    verification_code = models.IntegerField(_('verification code'), null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_user_agents',

    'home',
    'accounts',
    'policies',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
]
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You also need to create a custom `UserManager` class, the one that defines the `create_superuser()` method.

Comment: Something akin to the code in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911705/django-custom-user-model-user-creation-issue

Comment: Where would the code for the `UserManager` be placed? @zaquest

Comment: Try adding this to your settings.py, `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False`.

Comment: Adding `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False` didn't work. @raphael

Comment: Same file as `User` model should be fine. That's what `django.contrib.auth` does https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to creating custom user models, how do you reference `UserManager` to the project? @zaquest

Comment: Set `User.objects` to your new `UserManager` class https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L374

Comment: Check that `UserManager` is defined before `User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @zaquest for answering this question:

It needed a `UserManager` class in the models.py file.

**Code**

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email is required")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and     password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if kwargs.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff True")
        if kwargs.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser True")
        return self._create_user(email, password, **kwargs)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    full_name = models.CharField(_('full name'), max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(_('session id'), max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    verification_code_time = models.IntegerField(_('time left for session id'), null=True, blank=True)
    verification_code = models.IntegerField(_('verification code'), null=True, blank=True)
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```